# MATLAB vs Visual C++ for image processing

Tags: c#, java, visual-c++, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on an image processing project (Image Steganography), where I need to implement algorithms on various kinds of images, with a great emphasis on JPEG. The algorithms involve Fourier transforms, wavelet transforms, DCT, etc.

Which would be a better tool to implement? MATLAB or Visual C++  or C#? I am concerned with testing only the results of images and not the speed. So, can someone suggest me the best programming interface for my requirements?

Comment: How can we possibly know that? Are you MATLAB fluent? Is computing FFTs in C# something you can do?

Comment: Matlab's great for rapid prototyping - the language is easier and it's got an imaging toolbox & fairly big representation in the matlab file exchange. Not very good for collaboration though, because all your collaborators will need to purchase Matlab. As zmbq says though, depends on what you're comfortable with. One's a high-level language and one's a low(er)-level language.

Comment: I think that the people downvonting this should at least leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you Matlab because it is really easy and quick to write some code and see inmediate results. Actually when I work with computer-vision C++ code, I use Matlab-Engine to send variables to Matlab in order to plot and analize results, just because it is quicker and simpler and clarifies things a lot.

So if you don't need efficience and your enphasis is learning and understanding then Matlab is more "friendly".

Anyway the decision is yours. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**I agree with Jav_Rock . I am an image processing programmer. From my experience what I can say, MatLab is used for algorithm development and checking our logic and testing(Not all the time but most). Whereas open Cv or c and c++ coding we use directly in hardware. Any way for your purpose I suggest matlab. Have a happy coding…**